# Create view with all events till today + 2 more

Tags: views

to create block with events, which will be shown on homepage. Is it possible to create view, which will show all events, till today + 2 more, which are in future and closest to today date? Like it is shown on this diagram

2017-04-16 Event6 **nonvisible**

2016-09-15 Event5 **visible**

2014-03-12 Event4 **visible**

**----------------- today**

2013-12-20 Event3 **visible**

2012-12-20 Event2 **visible**

2009-12-20 Event1 **visible**

Comment: Can you grab the SQL Query view is generating now, and came up with changes to add these 2 more you need? If you can, then I can tell you how to implement it with views.

Comment: Well it should be something like this http://pastebin.com/KxpqvqBD

Could you please tell me how to implement it with views?

Comment: Is it possible to create union in Views ui? Or do I need to create my own module for this?